# Given current UTC time and specific hour of the day, return timezone offset (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs, timezone-offset

Given the current UTC time and a specific hour of the day, I want to find the timezone offset in minutes. The function below works (I think) for all timezones when the hour is midnight (excluding the few timezones that start at 30 and 45 minutes, but those are still covered by the timezone range if this runs every hour).

```
function getCurrentGlobalTimeOffset(currentGlobalTime) {
  var currentGlobalHour = dateFormat(currentGlobalTime, 'H');

  if (currentGlobalHour <= 11) {
    var currentGlobalOffsetStart = currentGlobalHour * 60;
    var currentGlobalOffsetEnd = (currentGlobalHour * 60) + 60;
  } else {
    var currentGlobalOffsetStart = (24 - currentGlobalHour) * -60;
    var currentGlobalOffsetEnd = ((24 - currentGlobalHour) * -60) + 60;
  }

  return {
    start: currentGlobalOffsetStart,
    end: currentGlobalOffsetEnd
  }
}
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to incorporate a specific hour. For example, if I want to get the timezone offset for when it is 9:00 AM Pacific time, the expected result at `2019-02-23T17:00:00.000Z` UTC time would be:

```
{
    start: 480,
    end: 540
}
```

I've also tried finding a library that does this but I haven't had any luck. As far as I can tell `moment.js` doesn't offer this capability.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to accomplish what you are asking with 100% confidence in the results, which is why you won't find a function for this in Moment.js or other libraries.  The reason is that time zone offsets of the world are presently in the range of UTC-12 to UTC+14, thus there is an overlap where such a function would have ambiguous results.

Consider as an example `2019-02-23T20:00:00Z` (UTC).  That is both `2019-02-23T09:00:00-11:00` (in American Samoa) and `2019-02-24T09:00:00+13:00` (in New Zealand) ([reference here](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20190223T200000&p1=1440&p2=1033&p3=22)).  So if the current UTC hour is `20` and the given local hour is `9`, should this function return `-11` or `+13`?

The best one could do would be to calculate both potential offsets, then see if one of them is out of range to exclude it.  Or, one could narrow the range such that it didn't overlap, if one didn't care about working with data for the entire world.

Comment: I wasn't aware that there is a time zone overlap. I'm going to modify it to calculate both potential offsets to account for the overlap. Thanks for your detailed answer!